# Why ApplyChanges() adds a new record?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I try the following code to update a row, but it adds a new one and I can't found where is my mistake.

here is my code:

```
public int SaveTerm(Term term)
{
    using (AshyanehDataContext dc = this.conn.GetContext())
    {
        if (term.TermID > 0)
        {
            dc.Terms.Attach(dc.Terms.Single(t => t.TermID == term.TermID));
            dc.Terms.ApplyChanges(term);

        }
        else
        {
            term.AddedDate = FarsiLibrary.Utils.PersianDateConverter.ToPersianDate(DateTime.Now).ToString("D");
            dc.Terms.AddObject(term);
        }
        dc.SaveChanges();
    }
    return term.TermID;
}
```

Comment: Your code is somehow unrelated to the question's title. Are you using STEs?

Comment: which part is unrelated? Method name?

Comment: I think dc.Terms.ApplyChanges(term); should update input parameter (term), but after this method call, I have a new Term. :(

Comment: And where is `ApplyCurrentValues` called in your code? You must make your question clear if you want to get answer because both `ApplyCurrentValues` and `ApplyChanges` methods can exist when usin EF but they are used in different scenarios.

Comment: You are attaching an object, therefore you are adding one in - don't attach, just select it, change it, apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change this part

```
if (term.TermID > 0)
{
    dc.Terms.Attach(dc.Terms.Single(t => t.TermID == term.TermID));
    dc.Terms.ApplyChanges(term);

}
```

to

```
if (term.TermID > 0)
{
    Term _term = dc.Terms.First(t => t.TermID == term.TermID);
    _term.Terms = term.Terms;
}
```

and it works